# For all $f: D_1(0) \to D_1(0)$ analytic with $f(\frac{i}{3}) = 0$, find $\displaystyle \sup_f\{\operatorname{Im} f(0) \}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the family of all analytic functions $f$ that map the unit disc onto itself with $f(\frac{i}{3}) = 0$. Find $M \equiv\sup\{\operatorname{Im} f(0) : f \in \mathcal{F}\}$.

I am preparing for my qualifying exam in complex analysis and I'm pretty stuck on this question. I will admit that I have not gotten very far and I'm just looking for a few hints to get me started. Hopefully then I will be able to post an answer to my own question.

A few thoughts. I know that that, for each $f \in \mathcal{F}$, $\operatorname{Im} f$ is a harmonic function and thus satisfies a maximum principle on each $\overline{D_r(0)} \subset D_1(0)$, $0 < r <1$. Could this be useful?

Also, I do know that the automorphism $\phi : D_1(0) \to D_1(0)$ given by $\phi(z) = \frac{\frac{i}{3} - z}{1 + \frac{i}{3}z}$ is an element of $\mathcal{F}$, with $\operatorname{Im} \phi(0) = \frac{1}{3}$, so $M \ge \frac{1}{3}$.

Any hints, or even a solution, are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simpler hint: Schwarz lemma.

Comment: @TedShifrin can you take a look at my answer and see how I did? Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take arbitrary $f \in \mathcal{F}$ and look at $f \circ \phi : D_1(0) \to D_1(0)$. Since $f \circ \phi (0) = 0$, the [Schwarz Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) applies. In particular, we get $|f\circ \phi (\frac{i}{3})| \le |\frac{i}{3}| = \frac{1}{3}$. But then $\operatorname{Im} f (0) \le |f(0)| = |f\circ \phi (\frac{i}{3})| \le \frac{1}{3} \implies M \le \frac{1}{3}$. Since we already mentioned that $M \ge \frac{1}{3}$ above, the proof is complete.

Comment: Looks right to me. Originally, I was suggesting Harnack's inequality, but it doesn't get us anywhere for this problem. Keep it in mind for trickier problems, though :)